# Automapper projection results in empty collection for nested Dto

Tags: automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .Net Core 2 webapi in which I am using automapper to map to Dtos. Everything works fine, except I am seeing an unexpected behaviour when I map an object to a Dto, and where the Dto also contains mappings for a collection. E.g

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();

CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
```

Where classes are like this

```
public partial class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
    public int ProductCount {return Products.Count;}
}

public partial class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**The following works as expected;**

The class is mapped, and the ProjectCount is correct in the Dto

```
public partial class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
    public int ProductCount{ get; set; }
}

_context.Orders.Include<>(Products).ProjectTo<>(OrderDto)
```

**But doing the following, the productcount is always zero**.

E.g. if I do this;

```
public partial class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDto> Products{ get; set; }
    public int ProductCount{ get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 _context.Orders.Include<>(Products).ProjectTo<>(OrderDto)
```

Why does this happen, and how can I ensure that it doesnt? This is a real world example where I need a property which references the collection - and I need it in both the base and the Dto. I can do the following which works fine, but it doesnt appear that this should be how it works...

```
public partial class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDto> Products{ get; set; }
    public int ProductCount {return Products.Count;}
}

public partial class ProductDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 _context.Orders.Include<>(Products).ProjectTo<>(OrderDto)
```

Answer (score 0):

I profiled the SQL and found that Automapper changes the way the query is formed. Without the nested projection, two queries are made;
[Queries are more complex than this and use joins, but you get the idea]

```
Select Id from orders 
Select Id,Name from products where productid in [select id from orders ]
```

With the nested projection, are executed for each nested Dto

```
Select Id from orders 
Select Id,Name from products where id=1
Select Id,Name from products where id=2
```